# UpdatePanelAnimationExtender doesn't work when UseSubmitBehavior=false

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I created a page with a button inside an update panel with an UpdatePanelAnimationExtender.  When the button property UseSubmitBehavior is set to false, the page throws the following error the first time the button is clicked.  This problem started after upgrading to AjaxControlToolkit v15.1.4 and .NET 4.5.1

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
Sys.Extended.UI.Animation.UpdatePanelAnimationBehavior._partialUpdateBeginRequest @ ScriptResource.axd?d=XXUsocPm2mzp3YAEY8x8Y7j6WnsFkZ3mD_ok19NSO-qjUqrlU8ioYjbwU0Cw5eBWEK3qGOKcTDGWRA…:74
(anonymous function) @ ScriptResource.axd?d=BZxEjT9seP4E_dbMgOxrqpjdA_OR6TXvgRJsLeld-igTpz-WyNZRwW91HnwWPdPPQHux3mKEkkZkJy…:47
(anonymous function) @ ScriptResource.axd?d=BZxEjT9seP4E_dbMgOxrqpjdA_OR6TXvgRJsLeld-igTpz-WyNZRwW91HnwWPdPPQHux3mKEkkZkJy…:3484
Sys$WebForms$PageRequestManager$_onFormSubmit @ ScriptResource.axd?d=jTr5ROtDjnYPwAYeyT86zhJOTSBtwOtiU52VRmjjD1D3asrfLsfZov5E1eFyG6jwvIsZc575A9p6Kj…:1284
Sys$WebForms$PageRequestManager$_doPostBack @ ScriptResource.axd?d=jTr5ROtDjnYPwAYeyT86zhJOTSBtwOtiU52VRmjjD1D3asrfLsfZov5E1eFyG6jwvIsZc575A9p6Kj…:824
(anonymous function) @ ScriptResource.axd?d=BZxEjT9seP4E_dbMgOxrqpjdA_OR6TXvgRJsLeld-igTpz-WyNZRwW91HnwWPdPPQHux3mKEkkZkJy…:47
onclick @ default.aspx:67

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            <ajaxToolkit:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender ID="upae" BehaviorID="animation" runat="server" TargetControlID="UpdatePanel1">
                <Animations>
                <OnUpdating>
                    <Parallel duration="0">
                        <ScriptAction Script="onUpdating();" />  
                     </Parallel>
                </OnUpdating>
                <OnUpdated>
                    <Parallel duration="0">
                        <ScriptAction Script="onUpdated();" /> 
                    </Parallel> 
                </OnUpdated>
                </Animations>
            </ajaxToolkit:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender>
            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                function onUpdating() {
                    //start doing something
                }
                function onUpdated() {
                    //stop doing something
                }
            </script>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can someone please try to reproduce this using v15.1.4?

Comment: I just uninstalled AjaxControlToolkit via NuGet.  I downloaded and ran the installer which installed the sample site.  I ran the UpdatePanelAnimation demo and it worked.  I then changed UseSubmitBehavior="false" on btnUpdate.  When I re-ran and click the button, it throws the error listed below.  When I click the button a second time, the animation works and no errors.  Each time I check/uncheck one of the effects and click the button, I get no animation on the first click and then it works on subsequent clicks.   Any thoughts on what I should try next?

Comment: Unhandled exception at line 1, column 1222337 in http://localhost:49617/Scripts/AjaxControlToolkit/Bundle?v=pkxsXT2k3m91OHFOSWKpPjmXp5eA4x28PiZfLhRs2ig1

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'id' of undefined or null reference

Comment: I repeated the process with v15.1.3 and had the same problem, but v15.1.2 worked without error.